# API Python script slows down after a while, how to make the code faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently running a Python script to collect concert data via the Sonkick api. Although the script is working, after a while the speed slows down tremendously. I am looking for the most efficient way to solve this.

Below you can find my script:

```
import urllib2
import requests
import json

from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('concerts_songkick.json')

#retrieve concert data for every artist in artistid.txt
def load_events():
        MIN_DATE = "2015-05-26"
        MAX_DATE = "2017-04-25"
        API_KEY= "##############"
        with open('artistid.txt', 'r') as f:
            for a in f: 
                artist = a.strip() 
                print(artist)
                url_base = 'http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/{}/gigography.json?apikey={}&min_date={}&max_date={}'
                url = url_base.format(artist, API_KEY, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE)
                try:
                  r = requests.get(url)
                  resp = r.json()
                  if(resp['resultsPage']['totalEntries']):
                    results = resp['resultsPage']['results']['event']
                    for x in results:
                        print(x)
                        db.insert(x)
                except:
                    print('cannot fetch url',url);

load_events()
db.close()
print ("End of script")
```

Comment: is it possible the api throttles your request based on number of requests? anyway you could use process pool to parallelize your code.

Comment: Don't use `string.format` to build URLs, at least not without properly URL-escaping the values beforehand. `MIN_DATE`, `MAX_DATE` and `API_KEY` are probably okay to use unescaped, but `artist` absolutely needs escaping.

Comment: Sounds like the API throttles you, I don't see any reason why execution will slow down.  You can always try printing the time taken for requests to  get each page, and see the time increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the CPU utilisation and Memory Consumption of the script:

```
watch -n 0.5 ps -ur
```

Check exactly which part of the code is clogging the memory. Use [Python Memory Profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).

```
...
from memory_profiler import profile
@profile
def load_events()
    ...
```

And log the memory consumption over time with the command:

```
python your_script.py > memory_profile_logging.log
```

This should give you a pretty good idea about what you need to optimise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing io bound operation try to use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) and fetch data from API asynchronously.